# Trouble getting a CSS menu to work - buttons won't show up

Tags: html, css

Evidently I'm kind of out of practice (its been a few months since I worked with HTML and CSS) because I copied some code off a site and when I previewed my site, it looked nothing like what was on the site. In fact, nothing even showed up.

Annyway, so here's what I was going for
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/flat_flipping_menu_buttons_vertical/

And here is the code. First my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>.Jack Murdock</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<div id="HeaderContainer"></div>





<br /><br />

<ul class="flatflipbuttons second">
<li><a href="photography.html"><span><img src="images/photography.png" /></span></a></li>
<li><a href="2d design.html"><span><img src="images/graphicdesign.png" /></span></a></li>
<li><a href="3d work.html"><span><img src="images/3dwork.png" /></span></a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html"><span><img src="images/contact.png" /></span></a></li>

</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

And then last but not least the part that has me completely lost, the CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
 body {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }

#HeaderContainer {
    width: 102%;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("title2.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: center;
}

.title {
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    color: #5f5f5f;


}

#nav {
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

.CenterContainer {
    width: 102%;
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
    height: 210px;
    padding-top: 10px;

}

div.img{
  height: 133px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 30px 20px;
  display: block;
  line-height:0;

}




#nav li a:hover {
    color: #9BACC4;
/* CSS Document */

a.current:link, a.current:visited {

    border-bottom:thick dotted #FFFFFF;
  }

#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}

.TitleImg {
position: relative;
top: 100px;
}

#nav2 {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 90;

    }

#nav2 li {
    float: left; 
    margin: 2px;
    }
#nav2 li a {
        display: inline;

        }

.frontimage {
        position: absolute;
        left: 500px;
        display: inline;
}

#nav {
    width: 25px;
    height: 600px;
}





ul.flatflipbuttons{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
-webkit-perspective: 10000px; /* larger the value, the less pronounced the 3D effect */
-moz-perspective: 10000px;
perspective: 10000px;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li{
margin:0;
display: block;
width: 100px; /* dimensions of buttons. */
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 0; /* spacing between buttons */
background: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li a{
display:table;
font: bold 36px Arial; /* font size, pertains to icon fonts specifically */
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
color: black;
background: #3B9DD5;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-out; /* CSS3 transition. */
-moz-transition:all 300ms ease-out;
transition:all 300ms ease-out;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li:nth-of-type(1) a{
color: green;
background: #3B9DD5;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li:nth-of-type(2) a{
background: #A1CD3A;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li:nth-of-type(3) a{
background: #80C5EC;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li:nth-of-type(4) a{
color: white;
background: #635746;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li:nth-of-type(5) a{
background: #F2C96D;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li a span{
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out; /* CSS3 transition. */
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li b{ /* CSS for text alongside button */
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -100%; /* starting vertical position of text */
left: 100%; /* horizontal position of text */
text-align: left;
text-indent: 10px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0.2s; /* CSS3 transition. 0.2s delay */
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out 0.2s;
transition: all 300ms ease-out 0.5s;
}


ul.flatflipbuttons li a img{ /* CSS for image if defined inside button */
border-width: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}


ul.flatflipbuttons li:hover a{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); /* flip horizontally 180deg*/
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
background: #c1e4ec; /* bgcolor of button onMouseover*/
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

ul.flatflipbuttons li:hover a span{
color: black; /* color of icon font onMouseover */
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg); /* flip horizontally 180deg*/
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
transition-delay: 0.2s;
}


ul.flatflipbuttons li:hover b{
opacity: 1;
top: -65%; /* vertical position of text onmouseover */
}

/* CSS for 2nd menu below specifically */

ul.second li a{
background: #eee !important;
}

ul.second li a:hover{
background: #ddd !important;
}
```

I have thee images there where the HTML is asking for them, but for some reason, the buttons themselves won't show up

Comment: You need to ask a question! What exactly did you want to fix from this?

Comment: So sorry! I am trying to get the buttons to show up properly as they do on the site that i linked to!

Answer (score 1):

i found that you have missed a closing "}" on the "#nav li a:hover" in your css code that is the mistake you have made

Comment: Wow, i would have never seen that! thank you so much!  I added in the extra "}" and now I actually have some buttons showing up! Progress! Unfortunately the buttons are colorless and show up as grey.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: your buttons are grey because of the _second_ class you assigned to `<ul class="flatflipbuttons second">`. Take it out and they'll have color.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the ending '}' in this css:

```
#nav li a:hover {
color: #9BACC4;
/* CSS Document */
}
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s8JSr/2/):

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied all your code into Notepad++, saving the HTML and CSS separately onto my Desktop, and created an images folder complete with the images and I had no problem. The code should work for you. As long as you copy the code into the following respective directories, it should be ok:

- Webpage.html - Sits at root level (e.g. Desktop) Portfolio.css
- Sits at root level (e.g. Desktop)
- photography.png - "images" folder as a
  child of root (e.g. Desktop/images)
- 3dwork.png - "images" folder as a child of root (e.g. Desktop/images)
- graphicdesign.png - "images"
  folder as a child of root (e.g. Desktop/images)
- contact.png - "images" folder as a child of root (e.g. Desktop/images)

Other than that, I can't see how the code could let you down.